how to show or hide ribbon button in dynamics based on role
function buttonvisibility() 
{
    
var roles = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.roles;

    if (roles === null) return false;

    var hasRole = false;
    roles.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.name.toLowerCase() === "system administrator") {
            hasRole = true;
        }
    });

    return hasRole;
}


What is your question?  How is it related to the posted code?
